# Есть ли какие-нибудь автоматизированные методы для выкладки модулей WildFly?

Tags: java, java-ee, wildfly

Добрый день. Судя по документации к WildFly 8, библиотеки к нему подключаются в качестве модулей, путём выкладки в директорию modules библиотеки с созданием иерархии папок и файла module.xml. Но порой бывает накладно и трудоёмко выкладывать всё дерево зависимостей проекта.

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы выкладывать модули не в ручную? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом, как совладать с библиотеками.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотеки подключаемые к WildFly и зависимости проекта - это не одно и то же.

Модулями к WildFly следует подключать только глобальные объекты которые будут затронуты в конфигурации самого WildFly, например, драйвера БД которые будут использованы при настройке Datasource.

Зависимости проекта пакуются при помощи ant, maven, gradle и подобных средств сборки в **WEB-INF/lib** каталог Вашего **war** или в **lib** каталог **ear** архива приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов выкладывания проекта.
1. С помощью IDE 
2. Компиляция war/jar/ear проекта и затем с помощью администрирования добавления данного проекта на сервер.
3. С помощью maven.

Или под модулями Вы имеете ввиду доп. функционал именно WildFly?